# Updating different elements of an array based on a ternary condition

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I am looking for the ternary operator syntax to do something like

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
if True:
    a[1] += 1
else:
    a[2] += 1
```

I have tried

```
a[1] += 1 if True else a[2] += 1
```

and

```
True and a[1] += 1 or a[2] += 1
```

Both threw an error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does someone know a ternary way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to move this expression into your index operation itself

```
a[1 if True else 2] += 1
```

Due to the specified grammar in python, you cannot do assignments in conditional expressions

```
>>> a = 1 if True else b = 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
```

This is also true for modifiers like `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that ternary operator isn't always the cleanest solution

```
a[ 1 if True else 2 ] +=1
```

Ps: just noticed I was too slow

Answer (score 1):

I think @CoryKramer's solution is more elegant, but just to give another way:

```py
a[1], a[2] = (a[1] + 1, a[2]) if True else (a[1], a[2] + 1)
```